# In Lightroom 3.5, can I use lens profile of Nikon AF 80-200mm f/2.8D ED for older non-ED version?

Tags: lens, nikon, lightroom, lightroom-3

In Adobe Lightroom 3.5 (and Camera Raw 6.5) it adds support for still in production **Nikon AF Zoom-Nikkor 80-200mm f/2.8D ED** (http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/846/cpsid_84666.html#main_Nikon)

My question is, am I able to utilise this lens profile for legacy lens **Nikon AF Zoom-Nikkor 80-200mm f/2.8** (1988-1992)?

The optics of these 2 lenses are identical hence they will have very similar weakness that can be corrected with same lens profile. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: What makes you say the optics are identical? The addition of ED elements is sure to give different characteristics in terms of distortion and aberrations. So my *guess* is that the profile would not be compatible. IIRC, the number of elements/groups is not the same either.

Comment: *@Itai* I got this assumption by looking at optics design graph in Ken Rockwell's pages. Since I can't find any official resource of 80-200mm AF, that's one of the few place I can find reference from...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you open a photo taken with that lens in the Develop module, then go down to Lens Corrections on the right side, it will probably tell you that it can't find a matching profile for that lens. You can then pick the lens profile to apply manually.

To test it, I just applied a Nikon 70-200 profile to a scanned TIFF image.

It's possible Adobe has made Lightroom smart enough to pick the right profile anyway, even though the EXIF info doesn't report the same way with these two lenses. If so, it'll work automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can give it a try and see how it looks.
If the image looks better to you after correction then you're onto a winner.
Othewise, not so much.

Give it a go.  Let us know how it works out.